# Take elements from a specific part of an array

Tags: python

How can I select and take elements from the third element to the last?

```
names = [1,2,3,45,12]
```

Comment: @PacketLoss that's not correct

Comment: check out slicing in the documentation..it's rather simple, if you have a list, you can slice a subset of itself by doing names[start:stop:step], where start=start index, stop=stop index, step=the step to take between start and stop, note python will include up to but not including the stop index..here is a good question that covers this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can slice an array from a certain index to the end or to another position as shown below

```
new_names = names[2:]
```

The above will slice from third to the last index

Comment: this will slice from the 3rd index position..which is actually the 4th element

Comment: I have fixed it @DerekEden

Answer (score 3):

```
names = [1,2,3,45,12]
```

You can access only certain parts of an array with slicing:

```
slicednames = names[2:]
[3,45,12]
```

This will save all elements from names to the new array, starting with the 3rd element.

If you put a second number in, you can specify the last element that is taken from the array as well:

```
slicednames = names[2:4]
[3,45]
```

This would copy only the elements 3 and 4. (The end limit is excluded, while the starting index is included.

If there is another colon followed by another number, its the size of the steps.

```
slicednames = names[::2]
[1,3,12]
```

So this would copy every second element of the array. (Starting with the first one, if not specified otherwise)

You should read about slicing, it is a basic and very useful tool to have in your belt.